# How to encode 8 4bit values into an Int32 and then get those back?

Tags: c#, encoding, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, 32-bit

How can I put 8 4bit (0..15 or 0..F if you like hex ;) ) values into an Int32 (int) in C# and get those back? I need these for a game that I am writing or more specifically, editor for it (which will feature vertex manipulation like in Notch's failed 0x10c) and since there's already some legacy code and few levels built, I really can't break the format so I can use Int64 and encode 8 8bit values using BitConverter class ;).

I'm not very good at bitwise ops and those who tried to explain these to me so far have failed so yeah. Need help.

Comment: You could use bit rotation (>> and <<) commands and the bitwise | to achieve this.

Comment: [What have you tried so far that isn't working?](http://whathaveyoutried.com). Little Endian/Big Endian? I'd probably use bitwise shifts.

Comment: Looks like a terrific opportunity to get good at it, kinda important. Use the .NET BitVector32 type to avoid thinking too much about it.

Comment: I think the OP wants general advice on the theory around this. I don't see this as a lack of effort issue. Not every question requires a full explanation of what has already been done. That will only make this harder to read as I see it

Comment: That's exactly what it is, Liam. And yeah, I've tried to understand bitwise so many times, but all the explanations I've found online or received from friends flew over my head so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main idea is to use left `<<` shift and `|` to *encode* and `&` and right `>>` shift to decode. Suppose the values are organized as array:

```
 byte[] data = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

 int result = data
   .Select((value, i) => value << (4 * i))
   .Aggregate((x, y) => x | y); // or just .Sum() - Jeppe Stig Nielsen's idea
```

**Edit:** *for loop* implementation:

```
 int result = 0;

 for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; ++i)
   result |= data[i] << (4 * i);
```

To *retrieve* the `index`-th value (`index` is in `[0..7]` range)

```
 byte item = (byte) ((result >> (index * 4)) & 0xF);
```

Comment: Could you rework your example to use regular for loop instead of LINQ? Unnecessary LINQ usage makes code hard to read. Thank you.

Comment: In this case, `.Aggregate((x, y) => x | y)` can also be written as `.Sum()` of course. The bit-wise 'or' is just addition when the operands have no set bits in common (no remainders).

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! I've written extension methods for Int32 and byte[] to easily decode/encode values based on your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to think about bitwise operations, you can set up a [BitVector32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32(v=vs.110).aspx), like this:

```
var bv = new BitVector32();
var sections = new BitVector32.Section[8];

// Create 8 4-bit sections
sections[0] = BitVector32.CreateSection(15);
for (var i = 1; i < 8; ++i)
{
    sections[i] = BitVector32.CreateSection(15, sections[i - 1]);
}

// Initialize the sections. Values will be 0F, 0D, 0B, ... ,01
for (var i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
{
    bv[sections[i]] = 15 - i*2;
}

// and output results
for (var i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0,2}: {1:X2}", i, bv[sections[i]]);
}
Console.WriteLine("bv value = {0:X4}", bv.Data);
```

### After comment

The questions of "conciseness" and performance are somewhat more involved than the comment would suggest. In a working program, the part of this code that sets up the sections could be done once, at program startup. For example:

```
BitVector32.Section value1 = BitVector32.CreateSection(15);
BitVector32.Section value2 = BitVector32.CreateSection(15, value1);
BitVector32.Section value3 = BitVector32.CreateSection(15, value2);
// set up others here
```

Then, when you want to access individual values:

```
BitVector32 bv = new BitVector32(someValue);

// get one value
int myValue = bv[value2];

// set one value
bv[value3] = 42;
```

Which is more concise than:

```
int myValue = (someValue >> 4) & 0x0f;
someValue = (someValue & 0xfffff0ff) | (42 << 8);
```

Performance is an open question. It's quite possible that the JIT compiler can generate inline code for those section operations.

Comment: Thank you, but I've already went with Dmitry's code. Since this is for a Unity game where GC performance is mediocre (understatement), I need to avoid as much allocations as I can and Dmitry's code does it job without too much allocations. It's also more concise.

Comment: @DariuszG.Jagielski: I saw that you accepted his answer. If it works for you, great. Others might be interested in this alternative. Also, see my update addressing the performance and conciseness.